# Is whole grain rye supposed to taste so coarse?

Tags: bread, rye

I've been making various white wheat flour breads for a while now and decided to try making a rye bread for the first time. What I didn't notice at the grocery store though is that the flour I bought was the whole grain variety. Ok, no problem I figured, can't be that different, the store bought whole grain breads here all pretty much taste the same as ones made of regular flour, maybe a bit drier and more boring.

The recipe I followed was pretty basic, 50% wheat flour, 50% rye flour, 65% hydration, yeast, salt, caraway seeds, 2 rises overnight.

Now having grown up eating rye bread, any rye bread with less than 100% rye is usually something I scoff at but I figured I'd ease into it and transition from something I know. Anyway, the dough preparation and baking all went nicely, the end result however was pretty damn awful.

For one, it just tastes like sadness, a mere shadow of the rye bread I'm used to. The worse part though - texture, its like I had added a handful of actual sand in the dough. You have to chew it for 10 minutes before swallowing so it doesn't feel like swallowing sandpaper. After eating a couple of slices, I could feel my throat scratchy for hours. Worst bread ever.

Anyway, am I missing something here? People can't actually be eating that stuff as is, why is it so coarse?

Comment: Was the rye flour particularly coarse itself? Were the caraway seeds scratchy?

Comment: @Sobachatina the caraway seeds were too big to be at fault, I can tell when I'm biting into one. The rye flour is so-so, most of it feels finer than white wheat flour but some bits in feel like tiny leaves, not coarse though, its very soft overall.